# Storing private key

Tags: android, security

What is recommended way to store private key in Android? I could not find solution I'd like.

These are the ones I do not really like:

- hardcoded private key in application (easy to extract)
- downloading private key from server after installation (not easy to download it from server too)
- generating key-pair after installation and sending public key to server (unique public key on server for every client)

Comment: can you generate/store the key in a yubikey and access it over NFC?

Comment: Key cannot be generated on client's side

Comment: generate on your side and send to them then...

Answer (score 0):

u can save materials for generate keys in a secret place(not required whatever place u like), use c code to generate private key(hard to extract).Unfortunately 
 there's no invulnerable security for front end, just raise the bar.

Comment: Storing parts of the key in app means that the key is already there and you just lost the security

Comment: yes, of course, do it just to raise the bar.  if u can not connect to the server, the only thing you can do is to save the key & raise the bar.  Event if u can connect to the server & get the key, and not save it locally. the only way to be secure is to get key from server by correct username and password that strong enough

Comment: other ways to be secure will be more complicated, such as create a dedicated certificates authority. u will still need network connection to a server.

Comment: Connection to server is not a problem, problem is, that if you try to download private key from server, attacker can do the same.

Comment: no , u can authenticate user's identity first, only send private key to identified users, and encrypt login data and the private key  with an asymmetric encryption algorithm. Attackers can do nothing except to obtain a quantum computer first if the password  is strong enough and the encryption key is long enough.

Comment: Thanks actually not what I'd like to do. I'd like to store private key in client's app and not annoy him with authentication.

Comment: You're welcome, but sadly it's really impossible to be invulnerable to save the key locally, except use a quantum key encryption which is impossible to accomplish without an experimental physicist in this field